# make a winform window in VBScript?

Tags: winforms, image, vbscript

can you make a winform  type window in VBScript? I want to make a simple practice app that displays a image when opened, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to create an [HTML Application (HTA)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496%28VS.85%29.aspx).  You still get the benefit of a plain text file that doesn't have to be compiled, and you can use HTML/CSS to create a GUI for the script.

Comment: so by making this HTA I can make a window and It doesn't need to compile so your still using notepad to write the code, does this mean I can still write in VBScript using the HTA window?

Comment: Yes, you can use VBScript or JScript.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what you asked, but I think you want vb.net not vbscript. Download the free visual studio for vb.net, and just have it create a new windows forms project (file/new project if I remember right). 
Vbscript is very old and there's  no way I know of to do windows forms stuff...it's more for old school asp pages or command line scripting via cscript.

Comment: so there's no way to at least get a image to be displayed by VBScript without using the internet explorer? thanks for the help.

Comment: It's IE or command line as far as I know. But you should check out vb.net it's much nicer and free also.

Comment: yeah I usually use visual C# but I'm just exploring this thing right now. thanks for the help.